# GPO - Power Button Action - Turn off the display

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

I want to set the ***Power button action*** to ***Turn off the display*** on multiple computers using a Group Policy. The value is available locally via ***Control Panel, Power Options*** but not via the Group Policy Management console.

Microsoft documentation, such as the following article, confirms these are the only group policy options.

> **[Conserving Energy with Group Policy | Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.05.energy.aspx)**
>
> Select the Power Button Action (Plugged In):
>
> Specifies the action that Windows takes when a user presses the power
>   button.   Possible actions include ***Take no action, Sleep, Hibernate,
>   and Shut Down***.

**Question:** Using a GPO (GPO setting, registry value, or script), how can I set the ***Power button action*** to ***Turn off the display***?

Comment: You cannot do this with GPO. The best option would just to set a GPO to turn off the screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TL;DR:** GPO Script
>
> powercfg  /setacvalueindex  SCHEME_CURRENT  SUB_BUTTONS PBUTTONACTION 4

---

Looks like the documentation and GPO just hasn't been updated. There is a value for it at least in powercfg it's just not documented.

**Powercfg usage:**

> powercfg  /setacvalueindex  {scheme_GUID}  {sub_GUID}  {setting_GUID}  {setting_index}

And you can set the scheme_GUID to SCHEME_CURRENT so you don't have to query it in your script

> powercfg /setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT  {sub_GUID}  {setting_GUID}  {setting_index}

There are a list of the GUIDs for options here:

[Power Settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/configure-power-settings)

And here are the powercfg usage docs:

[Powercfg options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options#option_setacvalueindex)

---

**The sub_GUID for power settings is:**

SUB_BUTTONS

4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347

**And the setting_GUID for the power button is:**

PBUTTONACTION

7648efa3-dd9c-4e3e-b566-50f929386280

**Setting Index/Values:**

0 - Do Nothing

1 - Sleep

2 - Hibernate

3 - Shut Down

**4 - Turn off Display** - Not documented but tested on my machine, works fine

---

So you would end up with one of the two below:

> powercfg  /setacvalueindex  SCHEME_CURRENT 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 7648efa3-dd9c-4e3e-b566-50f929386280  4

OR

> powercfg  /setacvalueindex  SCHEME_CURRENT  SUB_BUTTONS  PBUTTONACTION 4

And if you want to change it on all plans, you can list all the plans with **powercfg /list**, recurse through them replacing {scheme_GUID} with the power scheme

Comment: I had to run each call as `cmd /k powercfg <options>` for some reason. This got the job done. Bounty awarded.